# MediaWiki How to enable AutoComplete for InputBox? (or is there an alternative extension)

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I added an Input Box to our wiki's starting page. I want to mimic Google.

```
<inputbox>
type=search
break=yes
</inputbox>
```

and I have AutoComplete activated for Search
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Enabling_autocomplete_in_search_box

Now I realize, that I we have this cool auto completion for the search box but not for the prominent input box.

Is there a way to activate that? I was also already looking for alternative extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on ASammour input I searched again.

Updating `Mediawiki:common.js` helped

but only with

```
document.getElementById('searchform').action = '/w/index.php';
document.getElementsByName('search')[0].id = 'searchInput';
```

as described here
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Qun56cwugo953s9f

Comment: Thanks for the solution; however, the search box (InputBox) now ignores width settings, i.e. it now has the width of the whole available screen. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

There is a dummy way to do this, by following these steps:

- Make sure that JQuery UI is installed in your Mediawiki version. If not, then append it to your project.
- Add this code to your `Mediawiki:common.js` page:

```js
( function ( mw, $ ) {
    $( function () {
        $( '.searchboxInput' ).autocomplete( { //This is the class Name of your desired input
            source: function( request, response ) {
                // Create a new Api object (see [[RL/DM#mediawiki.api]]
                var api = new mw.Api();
                // Start a "GET" request
                api.get( {
                    action: 'opensearch',
                    search: request.term, // This is the current value of the user's input
                    suggest: ''
                } ).done( function ( data ) {
                    response( data[1] ); // set the results as the autocomplete options
                } );
            }
        } );
    } );
}( mediaWiki, jQuery ) );
```

- Clear the cache in the browser, then refresh the page. You will find that when you enter any character in that input, it will show you a list of related pages.

Comment: Thanks for this nice idea. But we are on MediaWiki 1.29.1
and https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Core_modules says, that jQuery UI is deprecated in 1.29

Comment: Based on that Idea... isn't it possible to use the SearchInputWidget  https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/OOUI/Widgets/Inputs ??